# memory usage of python multiprocessing script

Tags: python, multithreading, memory

I would like to measure the total maximum memory usage of python script, which is multiprocessing and uses ProcessPoolExecution module. How can i do it the right way?  Now my test skript reports bad values, memory usage responds only for main process. There is very small difference between single thread and multiproccessing variant of the script.

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def load_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = "https://www.httpbin.org/delay/0.1"
    URLS = [url for x in range(500)]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(load_url, url): url for url in URLS}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            url = futures[future]

            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{url} generated an exception: {e}")
            else:
                pass

    process = psutil.Process()
    print(process.memory_info().rss)
```

Comment: As the name suggests, `ProcessPoolExecutor` uses *processes*, so you're not really using threads.

Comment: You have the right , i have to clarify the question.